# How to use OR operator between classes in beautifulsoup findAll?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a trouble parsing html. I am working with a website that have some items in a list with different class names. What I'm trying to do is find them all in a single findAll like this:

```
page_soup.findAll("li", {"Class" : "Class1" or "Class2"})
```

I want to have "OR" between my classes.

Sample html:

```
<ol class="products-list" id="products">
    <li class="item odd">
    </li>
    <li class="item even">
    </li>
    <li class="item last even">
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select`() which is faster than `findAll`()

```
page_soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in page_soup.select(".odd,.even"):
    print(item)
```

**Code here**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<ol class="products-list" id="products">
    <li class="item odd">
    </li>
    <li class="item even">
    </li>
    <li class="item last even">
    </li>
</ol>
'''

page_soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in page_soup.select(".odd,.even"):
    print(item)
```

Comment: "Use Select() which is faster than findAll()"  - Did you measure this by yourself or it is documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Full working sample :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="Class1">Class 1</li>
        <li class="Class2">Class 2</li>
        <div class="Class1 special">Class 1 in div</div>
        <div class="Class2 special">Class2 in div</div>
    </ul>
</body>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")
result = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'li' and  
( tag.get('class') == ['Class1'] or tag.get('class') == ['Class2'] ))

print(result)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'descendants'

Comment: One Parentheses should be added at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<ol class="products-list" id="products">
     <li class="item odd"></li>
     <li class="item even"></li>
     <li class="item last even"></li>
</ol>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
data = soup.findall('li', class_=['odd', 'even'])

print(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.